# want to show submission confrimation message when form is submit

Tags: javascript, magento2, registration, confirmation, jquery-form-validator

this is my first question here on stack overflow. i'll be pleased if seniors come to help me with this. my registration form (when submitted/saved) shows red or green bar with the message If your form is submitted successfully or not. but it displays only for 1 second which is not enough and also doesn't catches eye, due to which customer thinks her.his form is not submitted. can someone guide me what should i do to correct this?
here is the js code i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addNewFileUpload()
    {
        var total_file_upload = jQuery('#total_file_upload').val();
        total_file_upload = parseInt(total_file_upload) + 1;

        var content = '<br><div class="control"><input  title="<?php echo __('Files'); ?>" type="file" name="varification_proof_' + total_file_upload + '" id="varification_proof_' + total_file_upload + '"  class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" /></div>';

        jQuery('#verification_proof_container').append(content);

        jQuery('#total_file_upload').val(total_file_upload);
    }
    function validate(id, field, limit)
    {
        console.log('#' + id);
        value = jQuery('#' + id).val();
        console.log(value.length + '=======' + limit);
        if (value.length == limit)
        {
            jQuery('#' + id + 'promptmsg').html(field + ' must contain ' + limit + ' characters');
            jQuery('div #' + id + 'promptmsg').css('display', 'block');
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery('div #' + id + 'promptmsg').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
    function validatenumber(id, field, limit)
    {
        console.log('#' + id);
        var value = jQuery('#' + id).val();
        if (value.length >= limit)
        {
            console.log(value.length + '=======' + limit);
            jQuery('#contactnumpromptmsg').html('Invalid contact number');
            jQuery('#contactnumpromptmsg').css('display', 'block');
        } else
        {
            jQuery('#contactnumpromptmsg').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
    function validateNTNnumber(id, field, limit)
    {
        console.log('#' + id);
        var value = jQuery('#' + id).val();
        if (value.length >= limit)
        {
            console.log(value.length + '=======' + limit);
            jQuery('#NTNnumpromptmsg').html('Invalid NTN number');
            jQuery('#NTNnumpromptmsg').css('display', 'block');
        } else
        {
            jQuery('#contactnumpromptmsg').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
    function validatepassword()
    {
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmation").value;
        if (password != confirmPassword) 
        {
            jQuery('#passwordmsg').html('Passwords do not match.');
            jQuery('#passwordmsg').css('display', 'block');
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery('#passwordmsg').css('display', 'none');
        }

    }
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

    function showTab(n)
    {
        // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        x[n].style.display = "block";
        //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
        if (n == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else
        {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == (x.length - 1))
        {
            document.getElementById("save").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else
        {
            document.getElementById("save").style.display = "none";
        }

        //... and run a function that will display the correct step 
        indicator:
        fixStepIndicator(n)
    }

    function nextPrev(n)
    {
        // This function will figure out which tab to display
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
        currentTab = currentTab + n;
        // if you have reached the end of the form...
        if (currentTab >= x.length)
        {
            // ... the form gets submitted:
            document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showTab(currentTab);
    }

    function validateForm()
    {
        // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x, y, i, valid = true;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
        {
            // If a field is empty...
            if (y[i].value == "")
            {
                // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                y[i].className += " invalid";
                // and set the current valid status to false
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and 
        valid:
        if (valid)
        {
            document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " 
            finish";
        }
        return valid; // return the valid status
    }

    function fixStepIndicator(n)
    {
        // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
        var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
        x[n].className += " active";
    }

</script>
 </div>
 <?php $session->destroy();?>
```

Comment: The end goal of the form submission is to get a new page as the response from the server.

Comment: you seem to have pasted a lot of code. In the future it would help a lot if you did a bit of debugging yourself and narrowed it down to a smaller chunk of code

Comment: @AndrewLohr: The code in question does not even seem relevant to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the form was submitted successfully should be shown on the page returned by the form post itself.

You seem to have posted a lot of validation related code, so you might be submitting the form, regardless of whether it is valid. You should do something like subscribe to the `submit` event of the form and cancel its default action (the submission) if it is not valid.